# How do I buy bundled insurance policies?

Tags: insurance, life-insurance, car-insurance, home-insurance

I currently have separate policies for home, auto, and term life insurance with three separate companies. I've read in multiple finance Websites that I should consider whether bundling policies with a single company could save me money. However, I'm at a loss as to how to do this.

I've found several leading insurance brands' Web pages advertise bundled policies. However, either the combinations are limited (e.g. auto & home only), or the quote form doesn't let me select more than one kind of insurance. I don't understand where a discount would come from, because nowhere am I asked whether I'm an existing customer. Also, I have yet to find a life insurance quote form that lets me sign up both my spouse and me at the same time.

I live in California, USA, but would welcome answers applicable to other jurisdictions.

Comment: Why not call your insurance agent?

Comment: @MichaelC. I don't have an insurance agent, nor do I particularly want one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 companies now that you work with. I would start there. Ask one of them to show you what would happen if you bought the other two policies from them.

This may not be something that they will show via the quotes generated on the web page. So you would be better off talking to a person who can generate a quote with that additional information. Make sure that you are comparing exact matches for the limits and options for the policies. Once you have done that with the first then do the same for the other two.

I would have to dig into my policy bills for life insurance, but I do know that the bills for the home and auto insurance do show exactly how much I am saving by having multiple polices.

Comment: I thought the task'd require multiple phone calls, but I was hoping some insurance companies would want to join me in the 21st century.